# How do I convert condition in batch script to PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have batch script using for. I want to convert it to PowerShell script, anyone can help about this?

#### This is the batch script

```
for %%i in (c d e f g h) do (
    dir %%i: > nul 2>&1
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        if exist %%i:\System.sav\CTO.txt (
        set WinDrive=%%i:
        )
    )
)
```

My expectation, I can convert it to PowerShell script

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to create a variable called WinDrive.  In Powershell, since variables start with a $ the closest conversion of that would be setting $WinDrive to a drive letter if that file is found on it. by doing

```
foreach($DriveLetter in @('c','d','e','f','g','h'))
{
    if(Test-Path "$DriveLetter`:\System.sav\CTO.txt")
    {
        $WinDrive = "$DriveLetter`:"
    }
}
```

If you want it to be a little more dynamic you can detect all the available drive letters on the system.

```
foreach($DriveLetter in $(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Root))
{
    if(Test-Path "$DriveLetter`System.sav\CTO.txt")
    {
        $WinDrive = "$DriveLetter"
    }
}
```

Comment: `Set WinDrive` sets an environment variable. This means that in PowerShell you probably want to do something like [`$Env:WinDrive = "$DriveLetter"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6) to get the same results.

Comment: @iRon Batch doesn't distinguish between environment variables and "normal" variables, so `set WinDrive=%%i:` is ambiguous in that respect. Whether the PowerShell code should be `$WinDrive = "${DriveLetter}:"` or `$env:WinDrive = "${DriveLetter}:"` depends on what the OP wants to do with the variable.